# number appended to variable for the type?

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, when debugging, I saw a number appended to the variable like
com.blah.blah.blah@82963fb

what does 82963fb mean? Is it the memory address?

Comment: Can you list a specific example from a debug session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the hexadecimal rendering of the "identify hash code" value for the object.  It is the value returned by the [`System.identityHashCode(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) method.  This method is also used to provide the default hashcode value for objects whose class hasn't overridden the `Object.hashcode()` method .

It is not necessarily the object's memory address, but in practice there is a relationship between the identity hash code and >>a<< memory address for the object.  (The value is typically based on the object's address at the time the method is first called.  The object's address may then change, but the hashcode value won't.)

(The entire string is produced by the default `Object.toString()` method.  The part before the `@` is the fully qualified class name of the object.)

Answer (score 1):

What you see is the output of Object.toString() method. Its defined as:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

So, what you are seeing after `@` is `Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`